# Using manual commit with multiple message consumer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, consumer

I'm very new with Kafka.
Using spring-boot kafka, I developed a publisher and a consumer using one Message object and manual ack. My code uses spring annotation. That's works perfectly.
Now, when I connect to production brokers, this one not send one Message but a list of message.
My listener method has the following signature:

```
@KafkaListener (topics="MessagesTopic", containerFactory="messageContainerfactory")
public void listen(@Payload Message message, Acknowledgment ack)
```

so I can acknowledge each Message. Good.
But now it's seems I must replace it with

```
@KafkaListener (topics="MessagesTopic", containerFactory="messageContainerfactory")
public void listen(@Payload List<Message> messages, Acknowledgment ack)
```

Even following the documentation it seems that I should use

```
@KafkaListener (topics="MessagesTopic", containerFactory="messageContainerfactory")
public void listen(@Payload List<Message> messages, Acknowledgment ack, Consumer<?,?> consumer)
```

1. Should I set batchmode to true ?
2. Now the question is : how can I acknowledge each message when this one has been completely handled?

Many many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one can help you either if you do want to manually commit offset.

If you do not want it then switch `setAckMode` to other value.

Here's this thing done the spring-way.

`CoreAutoConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@Import({KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CoreAutoConfiguration {

@Bean("batchKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> batchKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
    }
}
```

Then there goes your `Config` class:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        CoreAutoConfiguration.class,
        KafkaAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@EnableKafka
@EnableRetry
public class Config {
}
```

Finally the consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = "MessagesTopic",
        containerFactory = "batchKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void dataReceived(@Payload List<String> payload) throws RuntimeException {
    yourService.processIncomingData(payload);
}
```

And lastly, the properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=helloworld
spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
# this is size of incoming list if broker has this many entries, can be lower eventually
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=100
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But, I don't see where message is commited or not...

Comment: No exception thrown = ack in this case. If you need `batch.ack()` sort of thing then modify factory. But I doubt that this amendment worth it tbh - if no exception has happened, why not allow spring to commit batch for you